# A question about limitation

Tags: limits

Given two series $\{P_n\},\{Q_n\}$:

$$P_{n+1}=P_n+2Q_n,\,Q_{n+1}=P_n +Q_n,\,P_1 =Q_1 =1$$ How to get:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{P_n}{Q_n}}$$

If we let $a_n=\frac{P_n}{Q_n}$, any information we can get from it. I guess the answer is $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: With your notations, $\displaystyle a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+2}{a_n+1}$, and $a_n>0$ for all $n$. 
Show that
$$|a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}|\leq (\sqrt{2}-1)|a_n-\sqrt{2}|$$

Comment: Oh, thank you @Kelenner! Thanks for the hint, it is solved. I asked a stupid one. Because $a_n >1$, we have $|a_{n+1}-a_n|<\frac{1}{4}|a_n -a_{n-1}|$, so it converges. The fixed point of the function $\frac{x+2}{x+1}$ is $\sqrt{2}$. Your equation also works!